# Специфичный анимированный прогресс бар

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-animation

Вопрос в том, как сверстать такой компонент, который в идеале бы принимал на вход кол-во шагов прогресса.
С точки зрения css как я понял есть как минимум 2 подхода, это когда используют 2 дива вложенные один в другой, и у дочернего изменяется по клику свойство width, и также способ и использованием тегов списка li, и псевдо классов :before :after.
Я сверстал что-то отдаленно похожее на дивах, но проблема возникла на этапе отображения разделителей между шагами, кажется это всё-таки нужно делать с помощью списков.
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать данный прогресс бар с анимацией между шагами.

Вот конечный результат к которому я стремлюсь, svg со звездой на финише изменяет цвет:
[image: прогресс бар]

Comment: первый вариант => https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pogavWG , второй не то но просто так => https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/xxwdJmw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-container span')
const allspans = spans.length
const progress = document.querySelector('progress')
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle')
const svg = document.querySelector('svg')

let cntstep = 100 / allspans
    cnt = 0

let firstspan = 0
spans.forEach(t => {
   if(firstspan == 0) {
    t.style.opacity = '0'    
  }
   firstspan++
  t.setAttribute('data-step', cnt)  
  t.style.left = cnt + '%'
  t.style.transform = 'translate(-' + cnt + '%, -50%)'
  cnt += cntstep
  t.addEventListener('click', function (e){
    svg.classList.remove('clicked')
    progress.setAttribute('value', this.dataset.step)
    circle.style.left = 'calc(' + this.dataset.step + '% - 8px)'
  })
  
})
svg.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  this.classList.add('clicked')
  progress.setAttribute('value', 100)
  circle.style.left = 'calc(100% - 8px)'
})
```

```css
.progress-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.progress-container span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  z-index: 100;
  clip-path: ellipse(25% 40% at 50% 50%);
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: left .5s;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #41b0c1;
  border: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 200;
}
.svg {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: -10px;
  z-index: 210;
}
svg {
  fill: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 210;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5;
}
svg.clicked {
  fill: #41b0c1;
}
progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  
  height: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {  
  border-radius: 5px;  
  background: #eee;

}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  transition: width .5s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #a2e3d7, #41b0c1);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-container">
  <progress min ='0' max="100" value="0"></progress>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>   
    <span></span>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="svg">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="30"
    viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="30">
    <g>
        <path
            d="m256 82.637c-95.593 0-173.363 77.77-173.363 173.363s77.77 173.363 173.363 173.363 173.363-77.77 173.363-173.363-77.77-173.363-173.363-173.363zm0 326.726c-84.565 0-153.363-68.798-153.363-153.363s68.798-153.363 153.363-153.363 153.363 68.798 153.363 153.363-68.799 153.363-153.363 153.363z" />
        <path
            d="m498.337 290.378c6.404-9.956 13.663-21.24 13.663-34.378s-7.259-24.422-13.663-34.378c-4.287-6.664-8.336-12.958-9.635-18.665-1.386-6.087-.459-13.74.522-21.841 1.467-12.119 2.985-24.65-2.533-36.07-5.615-11.621-16.971-18.584-26.991-24.728-6.866-4.209-13.351-8.186-17.123-12.904-3.812-4.767-6.274-11.998-8.88-19.653-3.772-11.079-8.046-23.635-18.077-31.633-9.979-7.956-23.151-9.336-34.774-10.554-8.088-.847-15.728-1.647-21.29-4.327-5.372-2.588-10.659-7.975-16.256-13.678-8.265-8.422-17.633-17.968-30.34-20.853-12.233-2.776-24.047 1.462-35.472 5.563-7.769 2.787-15.108 5.421-21.488 5.421s-13.719-2.634-21.488-5.422c-11.424-4.1-23.237-8.339-35.472-5.563-12.707 2.884-22.075 12.43-30.34 20.853-5.597 5.703-10.883 11.09-16.255 13.678-5.562 2.679-13.201 3.479-21.29 4.327-11.623 1.218-24.796 2.598-34.774 10.554-10.031 7.998-14.306 20.554-18.077 31.632-2.606 7.656-5.068 14.887-8.88 19.654-3.772 4.718-10.258 8.694-17.124 12.904-10.019 6.144-21.375 13.107-26.99 24.728-5.518 11.421-4.001 23.952-2.534 36.071.981 8.102 1.908 15.754.522 21.841-1.299 5.707-5.348 12.001-9.635 18.665-6.404 9.956-13.663 21.24-13.663 34.378s7.259 24.422 13.663 34.377c4.287 6.665 8.336 12.959 9.635 18.666 1.386 6.087.459 13.739-.522 21.841-1.467 12.119-2.985 24.65 2.533 36.07 5.615 11.621 16.971 18.585 26.991 24.728 6.866 4.21 13.351 8.186 17.123 12.904 3.812 4.767 6.274 11.998 8.88 19.653 3.771 11.079 8.046 23.635 18.077 31.633 9.979 7.956 23.152 9.336 34.774 10.554 8.088.847 15.728 1.647 21.29 4.327 5.372 2.588 10.659 7.975 16.256 13.678 8.265 8.422 17.633 17.968 30.34 20.853 12.236 2.777 24.048-1.461 35.472-5.563 7.77-2.788 15.108-5.422 21.488-5.422s13.719 2.634 21.488 5.422c8.874 3.185 17.98 6.453 27.338 6.453 2.69 0 5.402-.27 8.134-.89 12.707-2.884 22.075-12.43 30.34-20.852 5.597-5.704 10.883-11.09 16.255-13.678 5.562-2.68 13.202-3.48 21.29-4.327 11.623-1.218 24.795-2.598 34.774-10.554 10.031-7.998 14.305-20.554 18.077-31.632 2.606-7.656 5.068-14.887 8.88-19.654 3.772-4.718 10.258-8.694 17.124-12.904 10.019-6.144 21.375-13.107 26.99-24.728 5.518-11.421 4.001-23.952 2.534-36.071-.981-8.102-1.908-15.754-.522-21.841 1.298-5.707 5.348-12.001 9.635-18.665zm-16.82-10.821c-5.033 7.824-10.237 15.914-12.316 25.046-2.158 9.478-.976 19.243.168 28.685 1.172 9.682 2.279 18.827-.687 24.966-3.063 6.338-11.016 11.215-19.437 16.378-8.029 4.923-16.332 10.014-22.289 17.463-5.998 7.5-9.147 16.751-12.193 25.699-3.167 9.304-6.16 18.092-11.613 22.44-5.407 4.312-14.628 5.277-24.389 6.3-9.434.988-19.189 2.01-27.886 6.2-8.52 4.104-15.297 11.01-21.851 17.688-6.951 7.083-13.517 13.773-20.492 15.357-6.544 1.483-15.164-1.608-24.29-4.883-9.038-3.244-18.384-6.598-28.244-6.598s-19.206 3.354-28.244 6.598c-9.126 3.275-17.746 6.368-24.29 4.883-6.975-1.584-13.541-8.274-20.492-15.357-6.554-6.678-13.331-13.584-21.851-17.688-8.697-4.19-18.452-5.211-27.886-6.2-9.762-1.022-18.982-1.989-24.389-6.3-5.453-4.348-8.445-13.136-11.612-22.44-3.046-8.947-6.196-18.199-12.193-25.699-5.957-7.449-14.259-12.539-22.289-17.463-8.421-5.163-16.375-10.039-19.437-16.378-2.966-6.139-1.859-15.284-.687-24.966 1.144-9.442 2.326-19.206.168-28.685-2.079-9.132-7.283-17.223-12.316-25.047-5.388-8.379-10.48-16.296-10.48-23.556 0-7.261 5.092-15.177 10.483-23.558 5.033-7.824 10.237-15.914 12.316-25.046 2.158-9.479.976-19.243-.168-28.685-1.172-9.682-2.279-18.827.687-24.966 3.063-6.338 11.016-11.215 19.437-16.378 8.029-4.923 16.332-10.014 22.289-17.463 5.997-7.499 9.147-16.752 12.193-25.699 3.168-9.304 6.16-18.092 11.613-22.44 5.408-4.312 14.628-5.277 24.39-6.3 9.434-.988 19.188-2.01 27.886-6.199 8.52-4.104 15.296-11.01 21.85-17.688 6.951-7.083 13.517-13.773 20.492-15.357 6.542-1.484 15.164 1.608 24.29 4.883 9.036 3.242 18.382 6.596 28.242 6.596s19.206-3.354 28.244-6.598c9.126-3.274 17.744-6.367 24.29-4.883 6.975 1.583 13.541 8.274 20.492 15.357 6.554 6.678 13.331 13.584 21.851 17.688 8.697 4.189 18.452 5.211 27.886 6.2 9.762 1.023 18.982 1.989 24.39 6.3 5.453 4.348 8.445 13.136 11.612 22.441 3.046 8.947 6.196 18.199 12.193 25.699 5.957 7.449 14.259 12.54 22.289 17.463 8.421 5.163 16.375 10.039 19.437 16.378 2.966 6.139 1.859 15.284.687 24.966-1.144 9.442-2.326 19.207-.168 28.685 2.079 9.132 7.283 17.222 12.316 25.046 5.389 8.381 10.481 16.297 10.481 23.558 0 7.26-5.092 15.177-10.483 23.557z" />
        <path
            d="m351.317 225.643-54.782-16.148-32.287-47.11c-1.864-2.72-4.95-4.347-8.248-4.347s-6.384 1.626-8.249 4.347l-32.287 47.11-54.782 16.148c-3.164.933-5.664 3.365-6.683 6.501-1.019 3.137-.426 6.574 1.585 9.188l34.828 45.264-1.57 57.09c-.091 3.297 1.45 6.426 4.118 8.365 2.669 1.939 6.121 2.438 9.229 1.332l53.811-19.134 53.811 19.135c1.09.388 2.223.578 3.35.578 2.084 0 4.147-.651 5.879-1.91 2.668-1.939 4.209-5.068 4.118-8.365l-1.57-57.09 34.828-45.264c2.011-2.614 2.604-6.052 1.585-9.188-1.021-3.137-3.521-5.57-6.684-6.502zm-47.749 51.576c-1.403 1.823-2.134 4.074-2.071 6.373l1.267 46.06-43.414-15.438c-1.083-.385-2.217-.578-3.351-.578-1.133 0-2.267.193-3.351.578l-43.414 15.438 1.267-46.06c.063-2.299-.668-4.55-2.071-6.373l-28.098-36.518 44.197-13.028c2.206-.65 4.121-2.042 5.421-3.938l26.05-38.009 26.048 38.008c1.3 1.897 3.215 3.288 5.421 3.938l44.197 13.028z" />
    </g>
</svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

первый, для себя, челендж ) еще есть над чем подумать, но уже спать хочу)

Comment: `spans.forEach( (span, i) => {` — второй параметр forEach как-раз считает элементы от 0 до length. Можно использовать его, вместо `firstspan++`. setAttribute тоже можно заменить `t.setAttribute('data-step', cnt)` → `t.dataset.step = cnt;` ... `progress.setAttribute('value', this.dataset.step)` → `progress.value = this.dataset.step;` )